# scopes in python3: lists as parameters of a function?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, scope

I'm studying for a python3 exam and came across this question:

*Given this snippet of code:*

```
def my_function(my_list_1):
    print("Print #1:", my_list_1)
    print("Print #2:", my_list_2)
    del my_list_1[0]  # Pay attention to this line.
    print("Print #3:", my_list_1)
    print("Print #4:", my_list_2)


my_list_2 = [2, 3]
my_function(my_list_2)
print("Print #5:", my_list_2)
```

*explain the output #3-#5:*

```
Print #1: [2, 3] 
Print #2: [2, 3] 
Print #3: [3] 
Print #4: [3] 
Print #5: [3]
```

I'm a little perplexed by these questions:

1. how does python know who 'my_list_2' is, within the 'my_function' `def` block of code?
2. Suppose I changed the last 3 lines of code from `my_list_2=[2,3]` to `pluto=[2,3]`:

   ```
    pluto = [2, 3]
    my_function(pluto)
    print("Print #5:", pluto)
   ```

this would generate a NameError which I think makes sense -- so why does it not throw an Error in the initial code?

3. inside the `def` block, how does *Print #4* for `my_list_2` reflect the changes applied to `my_list_1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put the list as a parameter, the interpreter puts the link to the object "list."

So, if you call

```
del my_list_1[0]
```

You modify the actual list you passed. So, as a result, both my_list_1 and my_list_2 lists are related to the same object, and you see one dropped element there.

An alternative code represent that is:

```
my_list_1 = [2, 3]
my_list_2 = my_list_1
del my_list_2[0]
print(my_list_1, my_list_2)
# [3] [3]
```

Answer (score 1):

`my_list_2` is a `global` variable. So it's accessible in your function. It's called `LEGB` in python which you can read about it [here](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/) .

And `list` in python is a mutable variable type. When you pass `my_list_2` as param to your function, if you make any changes to that, that would apply all over your code. Because it's mutable changes on it would happen in place.